# reload function but script inside function still execute jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to making web typing test.
so there is a button to reload function().
this function have script randoming words from string, and validate every user input to randomed words.

the randoming words script works perfectly, but the **keyup** script still executed.

```
var StopFunc;
function validationWords(StringFromPool){   
    // randomingWords function here   
    // script for focus to div
    $(".words-pool-container").on("keyup", function(e){
        //script for only accept a-z, space, and backspace
        // script for loop and if input keyup[i] == stringrandomwords[i] 
    })

 StopFunc = setTimeout(function(){validationWords(StringFromPool)}, 600)
}

function domReady(){
    StringFromPool=word();
    validationWords(StringFromPool);
}

$(document).ready(domReady)

$(document).ready(function(){
    // reload function button
    $(document).on("click", "#reload-btn", function(){
        clearTimeout(StopFunc);
        domReady();
    })
})
```

i do compare userinput and string based index. but when i press button reload, the index like looping. when i press once char, the index jump based on how many i click the reload button.

anyone know what i've missing here?

Comment: Event handlers assigned to elements don't magically disappear, just because you exited some function. Every time your `validationWords` is called, you are adding a new, additional keyup handler here.

Comment: @CBroe hooo, thanks for the clue, just searching about it. and i just need to add  .off("keyup")

Comment: If you run `validationWords()` n times, then you're adding `.on("keyup")` n times. It means that, when you press a keyboard key once, the validation script will run n times.

Comment: @JeremyThille i just know about it today lol. thankyou. just learning about programming few months ago. :D looks like i lack of knowledge about it. haha

Comment: One thing at a time :)